# gradle plugins classpath separation?

Tags: java, gradle, avro, velocity

I am trying to use two different gradle plugins in a project which utilize different versions of the Velocity templating language: one uses velocity 1 the other velocity 2. Specifically, one of these is the OWASP dependency check plugin ( https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.owasp.dependencycheck ) which uses velocity 2 and the other is a[n unfortunately ancient] gradle avro compiler plugin; versions of avro before 1.9 use velocity 1.x for generating java source code from schemas.

If I put both of these in a `plugins` block in `build.gradle`, avro compilation fails with this:

> Variable $velocityCount has not been set at /org/apache/avro/compiler/specific/templates/java/classic/record.vm[line 124, column 150]

Which is a symptom of using the velocity 2 engine with a velocity 1 template.

The gradle 7.x documentation (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#plugins_dsl_limitations) says this about the plugins DSL:

> This allows Gradle to do smart things such as: ... Allow different plugins to use different versions of dependencies.

But this does not seem to be the case. Is there a workaround for ensuring two plugins don't interfere with each other in this way? Or am I perhaps attempting to resolve this the wrong way?